# How to add a connection argument on a method

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

I am trying to add a connection argument to the method but cant get it working.
I want something like this:

**public void DeleteRows(string connectionName)**

this is what i have got so far

App.config

```
<add name="localDev" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=L;Initial Catalog=Dev;Integrated Security=False;User Id=S;Password=S;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
<add name="localQa"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=L;Initial Catalog=Qa; Integrated Security=False;User Id=S;Password=S;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
<add name="localPro" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=L;Initial Catalog=Pro;Integrated Security=False;User Id=S;Password=S;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

c#

```
    public void DeleteRows()
    {

        string ConnectionStringName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localDev"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection com = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringName);
        try
        {
            com.Open();
            // delete
            string sqlDelete = "TRUNCATE TABLE VISUALISATION";
            SqlCommand cmdD = new SqlCommand(sqlDelete, com);
            cmdD.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            com.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: `public void DeleteRows(string connString) { SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString); ..... }`? or `public void DeleteRows(string connName) { string ConnectionStringName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connName].ConnectionString; ... }`?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? If you want your delete rows to have a method signature of `public void DeleteRows(string connectionName)` then update it as such.

Comment: @Tim Thanks alot, The problem was: i was using connName between "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Tim answered.. you can pass the connection string.. or connection name added in configuration file..

if want to pass only connection name then try the below one..

```
public void DeleteRow(string ConnectionName)
{
   string ConnectionString = 
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionName].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
   /*
    *  your code goes here.. 
    * 
    */
}
```

call it form your code like

```
DeleteRow("localDev")
//or
DeleteRow("localQa")
//or
DeleteRow("localPro")
```

Hope it make sense.!